# Why in swift are variables option in a function but not in playground

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

I am puzzled. I need to compare product date codes. they look like 12-34-56. I wrote some code to break the parts up and compare them.  this code works fin in the play ground.  But when i make it a function in a view controller values come up NIL and i get a lot of "Optional("12-34-56")" values when printed to the log or viewed in a break. I tried unwrapping in many locations but nothing takes.? don't be confused by the variables date and month because they are not product codes can have 90 days and 90 months depending on the production machine used.

```
func compaireSerial(oldNumIn: NSString, newNumIn: String) -> Bool {
        // take the parts of the number and compare the pics on at a time.         
        // Set up the old Num in chunks
        let oldNum = NSString(string: oldNumIn)
        let oldMonth = Int(oldNum.substringToIndex(2))
        let oldDay = Int(oldNum.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 3, length: 2)))
        let oldYear = Int(oldNum.substringFromIndex(6))
        print(oldMonth,oldDay, oldYear)


        // Set up the new Num in chunks
        let newNum = NSString(string: newNumIn)
        let newMonth = Int(newNum.substringToIndex(2))
        let newDay = Int(newNum.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 3, length: 2)))
        let newYear = Int(newNum.substringFromIndex(6))
        print(newMonth, newDay, newYear)

        // LETS Do the IF comparison steps.
        if oldYear < newYear {
            return true
        } else if oldMonth < newMonth {
            return true
        } else if oldDay < newDay {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

May thanks to any one.  Im totally stumped

Comment: Your code are all over the place. Is there any reason why `oldNumIn` is `NSString` while `newNumIn` is `String`?

Comment: hello. the different string are leftover from all the many iterations i have been trying. I have edited this simple function so many ways in the past 3 hours I lost track of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

All `Int()` initializers with `String` parameters return always an optional `Int`.
The realtime result column in a Playground doesn't indicate the optional but printing it does.

```
let twentyTwo = Int("22")  |  22
print(twentyTwo)           |  "Optional(22)\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how i can delete my question so ill post this to let others know it is fixed.  Turns out the auction works okay but the NSUserDefaults value coming in was optional. So i was feeding the optional in.  After unwrapping the NSUser value all works.